# Responsive Nav - Drop Down Links

Tags: html, css

Been playing around again with website design.

How can I make the navigation bars links align center without messing up the drop down links?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown

I want the navigation bar to stay as it is, but the links in the middle, but everything I try which does make the links centered breaks the responsive drop down links when window is collapsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could e.g. change `.topnav` to

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

but you have to remove that styling in the media queries, e.g.:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav a {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm now struggling in making the actual drop down a link, when I place <a href="#"> around the button. It breaks, and pushes the links up/down?

Image Below
https://ibb.co/yy94JCf

<div class="dropdown"><a href="#">
      <button class="dropbtn">PRODUCTS
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button></a>
   
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Laminates</a>
        <a href="#">Breakfast Bars</a>
        <a href="#">Upstands</a>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: UX-wise that is a really bad idea see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/in-praise-of-the-unambiguous-click-menu/) for explanation, and the comments here aren't the right place to explain that. Maybe open another question for that.

Also don't forget to mark my answer as solution if it solved your problem.